# About an integral from the MIT integration bee 2022

Tags: integration, solution-verification

In the Knockout Match 3 in the MIT integration bee 2022 participants were asked to compute the following integral:

> \begin{align}
> \int_0^{+\infty}{\sum_{k = \lfloor{x}\rfloor}^{+\infty}{\frac{2^{-k}}{k+1}}\mathrm{d}x}\tag{1} \end{align}

and the given answer is $4$. However, when I tried to compute the integral, I did not get $4$ and perhaps my logic is somehow flawed. First, I tried to break the integral into an infinite sum of definite integrals so $(1)$ becomes:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{+\infty}{\sum_{k = \lfloor{x}\rfloor}^{+\infty}{\frac{2^{-k}}{k+1}}\mathrm{d}x}&=\lim_{t \to +\infty}{\sum_{n = 0}^{t}\left[{\int_{n}^{n+1}{\left(\sum_{k= \lfloor{x}\rfloor}^{+\infty}{\frac{2^{-k}}{k+1}}\right)\mathrm{d}x}}\right]} \\
&=\lim_{t \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{t}\left[{\int_{n}^{n+1}{\left(\sum_{k = n}^{+\infty}{\frac{2^{-k}}{k+1}}\right)\mathrm{d}x}}\right]} \\
&= \lim_{t \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{t}{\left[2^{-n}\int_{n}^{n+1}{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{2^{-k}}{k+n+1}}\right)\mathrm{d}x}\right]}} \\
&= \lim_{t \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{t}}{\left[2^{-n}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{2}, \ 1,\ n+1\right)\right]} \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch transcendent function. But we have that
\begin{align}
\Phi\left(\frac{1}{2},\ 1,\ n+1\right) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-(n+1)t}}{1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}}dt} \\
&= \int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2u}\right)u^{n+2}}\mathrm{d}u} \\
&= \int_{1}^{\infty}\left({\frac{2^{n+2}}{2u-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{\frac{2^{n-k+2}}{u^{k}}}}\right)\mathrm{d}u \\
&=\Biggr[2^{n+1}\ln{(2u-1)}-2^{n+1}\ln{u}-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}{2^{n-k+2}\frac{u^{1-k}}{1-k}}\Biggr]_1^{\infty} \\
&= 2^{n+1}\ln{2}-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}{\frac{2^{n-k+2}}{1-k}}
\end{align}

so $(2)$ becomes:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{+\infty}{\sum_{k = \lfloor{x}\rfloor}^{+\infty}{\frac{2^{-k}}{k+1}}\mathrm{d}x}&=\lim_{t \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{t}\left({2\ln{2}-2^{-n}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}}\frac{2^{n-k+2}}{1-k}\right)} \\
&=\lim_{t \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{t}\left({2\ln{2}-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}}\frac{2^{-k+2}}{1-k}\right)}
\end{align}
but I can't compute the last sum in terms of $n$ so that I may compute the final infinite sum. I know this is a bit too far gone, but is there maybe some way to save this approach and go forward? Also, any clever solutions of the problem, more elementary, are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure how they're getting $4$; I suspect I'm doing something wrong to end up with $2$, but maybe the idea is on the right track. *If* you can prove it's okay to do so, interchanging the innermost sum in the lines above $(2)$ gives$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac1{2^k (k+1)}=2$$[acc. to WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2F%282%5Ek*%28k%2B1%29%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%2C+%7Bk%2C+n%2C+Infinity%7D%5D)

Comment: @user170231 Where have you interchanged sums? I believe these are the sums that appear once the integral has vanished (it obviously does as $n+1-n=1$) in their order. I did try that at first but didn't get much further. I couldn't actually prove that the sequence converged to $2$. Convergence is easy to prove, but a few tries after terminating the sequence at partial sums I figured that we always had a $2^{n+1}\ln{2}$ minus the sum I can't figure out. I have actually seen sequences like these (hence the Lerch transcendent which worked then with exact values and contours) Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm referring to$$\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=\lfloor x\rfloor}^\infty\frac1{2^k(k+1)}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\color{blue}{\int_n^{n+1}}\color{red}{\sum_{k=n}^\infty}\frac1{2^k(k+1)}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\color{red}{\sum_{k=n}^\infty}\color{blue}{\int_n^{n+1}}\frac1{2^k(k+1)}\,dx$$(assuming equality, of course; the missing factor of $2$ suggests otherwise)

Comment: But the sum is not in terms of $x$ so that it may be pulled out of the integral without worry. At least I think so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
I:=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=\lfloor x\rfloor}^\infty\frac{2^{-k}}{k+1}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\int_n^{n+1}}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{2^{-k}}{k+1}\,dx 
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{2^{-k}}{k+1}. \tag{1}
$$
Writing each internal sum of $(1)$ in a separate line, we obtain
\begin{align}
I=&\,\,
1+\frac{2^{-1}}{2}+\frac{2^{-2}}{3}+\ldots \\
&\phantom{\,\,1}+\frac{2^{-1}}{2}+\frac{2^{-2}}{3}+\ldots \\
&\phantom{\,\,1+\frac{2^{-1}}{2}}+\frac{2^{-2}}{3}+\ldots \\
&\phantom{\,\,1+\frac{2^{-1}}{2}+\frac{2^{-2}}{3}}+\ldots  \tag{2}
\end{align}
If we now reorder the terms along the vertical lines, we can rewrite $(2)$ as
$$
I=1+2\,\frac{2^{-1}}{2}+3\,\frac{2^{-2}}{3}+\ldots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}=2, \tag{3}
$$
which is the same result obtained by @user170231.

Comment: That was incredibly easy. Any other way you think the $\Phi$ approach could be saved? Is it even correct? I'll accept your answer either way.

Comment: Yes, it can be saved. Notice that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}\Phi\left(\frac{1}{2},1,n+1\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(n+1)t}}{1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\right)^2}.
$$
Changing the variable of integration to $u=\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}$, the integral can be rewritten as $$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{2}{(1-u)^2}\,du.$$I leave the final step to you.